# Wrapping cumulative sum from a set starting row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data frame that looks a bit like this:

```
wt <- data.frame(region = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)), time = c(1:5, 1:5), 
                 start = c(rep(2,5), rep(4, 5)), value = rep(1, 10))
```

The values in the `value` column could be any numbers (I am working in a very large data set), but each region will be over an equal-length time series and have a single starting point.

I want to perform a cumulative sum within each region that begins accumulating at the starting point, continues forward in the time series, and wraps to the rows before the starting point in the time series.

The full data table, WITH the intended result, would look like this:

```
region    time     start    value    result
A         1        2        1        5
A         2        2        1        1
A         3        2        1        2
A         4        2        1        3
A         5        2        1        4
B         1        4        1        3
B         2        4        1        4
B         3        4        1        5
B         4        4        1        1
B         5        4        1        2
```

A simple transformation of the time column followed by `cumsum` does not work, since the function cares about row order and not any particular factor.

With that in mind, I am operating on a huge data table, and runtime is absolutely a concern, so any solution ***must*** avoid re-ordering rows.

Ideas of how to do this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Consider time to be a cycle such as hours in a day - and for example, if the start time is 2, that means observations start at one instance of time 2 and end at the next time 1.

Comment: The logic of 'result is not clear

Comment: @akrun Accumulation of the `value` column begins where `time == start` and ends where `time == start-1`. If the start time isn't 1, the accumulation should wrap around to the first row of the region.

Comment: In that case, the expected output seems to be incorrect.  If we take the region  'A', then time == start is second row, and time==start-1 is 3rd row,

Comment: @akrun how so? It starts a wrapping cumulative sum on `time==2` for region A and `time==4` for region B

Comment: You said you want *"a cumulative sum within each region"*, meaning you shouldn't be wrapping into region B time 4. Your previous comment is inconsistent. This is rather confusing: since `$region` and `$start` are perfectly confounded, your example is a bit difficult to use to frame you problem. Can you either clarify your grouping logic or generate a working/reproducible sample dataset?

Comment: Suppose the time series represented 24 hours, and each region had observations with a 24-hour time column ordered 0:23. if observations  started at 5am (`time==5`) one day and ended at 4am (`time==4`) the next, we would want to have a cumulative sum that represented the observations in the order that they occurred, so the order of times for the cumulative sum would be `c(5:23, 0:4)`. Does that clear up what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in an efficient way with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(wt)[time>=start, result := seq_len(.N), region]
wt[, Max := max(result, na.rm = TRUE), region]
wt[is.na(result), result := Max +seq_len(.N) , region][, Max := NULL][]
#   region time start value result
#1:      A    1     2     1      5
#2:      A    2     2     1      1
#3:      A    3     2     1      2
#4:      A    4     2     1      3
#5:      A    5     2     1      4
#6:      B    1     4     1      3
#7:      B    2     4     1      4
#8:      B    3     4     1      5
#9:      B    4     4     1      1
#10:     B    5     4     1      2
```

Comment: This looks like it works! Where in the code is the `value` column selected in order to calculate the result?

Comment: @ctenochaetus  Okay, I see that your 'value' column were a sequence, so yes, you can change it to `cumsum` if there are other values like the one you posted

Answer (score 1):

akrun's solution works for the example I gave (hence I accepted it as the answer), but here's a version that works for any values in the `value` column:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(wt)[time>=start, result := cumsum(value), region]
wt[, Max := max(result, na.rm = TRUE), region]
wt[is.na(result), result := Max +cumsum(value) , region][, Max := NULL][]
```

Just adding the... unfortunately named `cumsum` function in place of a calculated sequence.